# LinearLayout Id

Tags: android, eclipse

Im very noobish here so forgive my question.

Im making a LinearLayout programatically, and it seems to be working alright.

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this); 
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("hej");
ll.addView(tv);
setContentView(ll);
```

Now what do I do, so I can refer to the LinearLayout view as R.id.container (easier to remember stuff that way) - I cant find out how to set id as other as int (as the function.

Comment: You can also use [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) and [getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) to reference `View`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/res/values` folder, make a file called `ids.xml` and add this:

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="container" />
</resources>
```

Then in java you would write

```
linearLayout.setId(R.id.container);
```

Comment: Oh - haha. I feel stupid now :), Ill accept once the minimum time has been spent.